# Почему происходит смещение координат круга в формуле нахождения центра вписанной окружности?

Tags: javascript, canvas, математика, геометрия, формулы

Как решить эту проблему и почему она происходит?

```css
body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
  <script>
    function getDist(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))
    }

    function getBiss(o, p0, p1) {
      let vecAngle1 = Math.atan2(p0.x - o.x, p0.y - o.y) * (-1) + Math.PI / 2
      if (vecAngle1 < 0) vecAngle1 += Math.PI * 2
      let vecAngle2 = Math.atan2(p1.x - o.x, p1.y - o.y) * (-1) + Math.PI / 2
      if (vecAngle2 < 0) vecAngle2 += Math.PI * 2

      let max = Math.max(vecAngle1, vecAngle2),
        min = Math.min(vecAngle1, vecAngle2);
      let biss = (max - min) / 2,
        biss2 = (Math.PI * 2 - (max - min)) / 2

      return [min + biss, max + biss2]
    }

    function drawBiss(o, p0, p1) {
      let biss = getBiss(o, p0, p1)[0],
        biss2 = getBiss(o, p0, p1)[1]

      ctx.moveTo(o.x, o.y)
      ctx.lineTo(o.x + Math.cos(biss) * w, o.y + Math.sin(biss) * w)

      ctx.moveTo(o.x, o.y)
      ctx.lineTo(o.x + Math.cos(biss2) * w, o.y + Math.sin(biss2) * w)
    }

    function cross(A1x, A1y, A2x, A2y, B1x, B1y, B2x, B2y) {
      let x = -((A1x * A2y - A2x * A1y) * (B2x - B1x) - (B1x * B2y - B2x * B1y) * (A2x - A1x)) / ((A1y - A2y) * (B2x - B1x) - (B1y - B2y) * (A2x - A1x));
      y = ((B1y - B2y) * (-x) - (B1x * B2y - B2x * B1y)) / (B2x - B1x);
      return {
        x: x,
        y: y
      }
    }

    function crossLine(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
      let res = cross(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y, p4.x, p4.y)
      return res;
    }

    function getCentre(p1, p2, p3) {
      let a = Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)),
        b = Math.sqrt((p3.x - p2.x) * (p3.x - p2.x) + (p3.y - p2.y) * (p3.y - p2.y)),
        c = Math.sqrt((p3.x - p1.x) * (p3.x - p1.x) + (p3.y - p1.y) * (p3.y - p1.y));

      let p = (a + b + c) / 2,
        S = 0.5 * Math.abs(((p2.x - p1.x) * (p3.y - p1.y) - (p3.x - p1.x) * (p2.y - p1.y)));

      let r = S / p;

      let x0 = ((p1.x + p2.x - 2 * p3.x) * ((p3.y - p1.y) * (p2.x + p3.x - 2 * p1.x) + p1.x * (p2.y + p3.y - 2 * p1.y)) - p3.x * (p2.x + p3.x - 2 * p1.x) * (p1.y + p2.y - 2 * p3.y)) / ((p2.y + p3.y - 2 * p1.y) * (p1.x + p2.x - 2 * p3.x) - (p2.x + p3.x - 2 * p1.x) * (p1.y + p2.y - 2 * p3.y));
      y0 = ((x0 - p1.x) * (p2.y + p3.y - 2 * p1.y) / (p2.x + p3.x - 2 * p1.x)) + p1.y;

      return {
        x: x0,
        y: y0,
        r: r
      }
    }

    var canv = document.querySelector('#canv'),
      ctx = canv.getContext('2d'),
      w = canv.width = window.innerWidth,
      h = canv.height = window.innerHeight;
    var log = val => console.log(val)
    var und;

    var dots = [],
      opts = {
        radius: 3
      };
    var deletedI;

    canv.onmousedown = e => {
      if (e.which != 3) {
        if (dots.length < 3) {
          if (deletedI === undefined) {
            dots.push({
              x: e.x,
              y: e.y
            })
            canv.onmousemove = e => {
              dots[dots.length - 1] = {
                x: e.x,
                y: e.y
              }
            }
          } else {
            dots.splice(deletedI, 0, {
              x: e.x,
              y: e.y
            })
            canv.onmousemove = e => {
              dots.splice(deletedI, 1, {
                x: e.x,
                y: e.y
              })
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    canv.onmouseup = () => {
      canv.onmousemove = und;
    }
    canv.oncontextmenu = e => {
      canv.onmousemove = und;
      e.preventDefault()
      let arrForFilter = [];
      dots.forEach(cur => {
        let dist = getDist(e.x, e.y, cur.x, cur.y)
        arrForFilter.push(dist)
      })
      dots.forEach((cur, i) => {
        let dist = getDist(e.x, e.y, cur.x, cur.y)
        if (dist == Math.min.apply(Math, arrForFilter)) {
          dots.splice(i, 1);
          deletedI = i
        }
      })
      arrForFilter = [];
    }

    function anim() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
      dots.forEach((cur, i) => {
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(cur.x, cur.y, opts.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.closePath()
      })
      if (dots.length == 2) {
        ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x, dots[0].y);
        ctx.lineTo(dots[1].x, dots[1].y);
        ctx.stroke()
      }
      if (dots.length == 3) {
        ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x, dots[0].y);
        ctx.lineTo(dots[1].x, dots[1].y);
        ctx.lineTo(dots[2].x, dots[2].y);
        ctx.lineTo(dots[0].x, dots[0].y);

        drawBiss(dots[0], dots[1], dots[2])
        drawBiss(dots[1], dots[2], dots[0])
        drawBiss(dots[2], dots[1], dots[0])

        let centre = getCentre(dots[0], dots[1], dots[2])
        ctx.arc(centre.x, centre.y, centre.r, 0, Math.PI * 2)

        ctx.stroke()
      }

      window.requestAnimationFrame(anim)
    }

    anim()
  </script>
```

Comment: Ну видимо из-за неправильного вычисления координат центра. Откуда вы взяли эти подозрительные формулы?

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread414197.html и переписал на js.

Comment: Если у вас уже есть готовые длины сторон, то координаты центра вычисляются по простой формуле: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Cartesian_coordinates. А копирование подозрительного страшного кода будет приводить лишь к странным результатам.

Comment: @Василий Я уже говорил Вам, что Вы идете по скользкой дорожке бездумного [пере]кодирования формул. Если так будет и дальше, Вам постоянно будут требоваться такие проверяльщики, которых Вы пытаетесь здесь найти.

Comment: Так проблема в том, что я не могу найти нормальных формул и приходится заниматься такой фигней.

Comment: @Василий Дело не в "нахождении правильных формул", а в понимании того, что Вы делаете. Вы уже посчитали параметры для прямых, являющихся биссектрисами углов треугольника. Пересечение любой пары этих биссектрис даст Вам центр вписанной окружности. Расстояние от этого центра до любой стороны - радиус. Пересечение двух прямых и расстояние от точки до прямой - это две-три строчки нехитрых вычислений, в которых легко разобраться.

Comment: Вычислять центр, как пересечение биссектрис - грубый и нестабильный подход. Само построение биссектрис в данном коде - через явное вычисление углов и тригонометрию - тоже грубый и нестабильный подход. Еще раз: если вы уже знаете длины сторон, то положение центра окружности элементарно вычисляется как взвешенное усреднение координат углов треугольника. Простейшая формула дана по ссылке. Она же: http://fxdx.ru/page/centr-vpisannoj-v-treugolnik-okruzhnosti

Comment: @AnT "... взвешенное усреднение координат ..." - дальнейшее он договаривал в пустоту.

Comment: @Igor: Не преувеличивайте. "Взвешенное усреднение" - не настолько страшный термин, чтобы пугать даже новичков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за формулы и советы, так вот по ним я составил функцию

```js
function getCentre(p1,p2,p3) {
 let p1Len = getDist(p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y),
 p2Len = getDist(p1.x, p1.y, p3.x, p3.y),
 p3Len = getDist(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y)
 return {
  x: (p1Len*p1.x + p2Len*p2.x + p3Len*p3.x) / (p1Len + p2Len + p3Len),
  y: (p1Len*p1.y + p2Len*p2.y + p3Len*p3.y) / (p1Len + p2Len + p3Len),
  r: Math.sqrt(((-p1Len+p2Len+p3Len)*(p1Len-p2Len+p3Len)*(p1Len+p2Len-p3Len))/(4*(p1Len+p2Len+p3Len)))
 }
}
```

Спасибо огромное

Comment: Замечательно. Также: площадь треугольника по координатам вершин тоже можно вычислять без применения тяжеленной формулы Герона. У вас в исходном варианте `S` вычисляется как раз более "разумным" способом - как половина площади "натянутого" на вершины параллелограмма.